# Whats the state for SSH on Windows in libgit2sharp

Tags: windows, ssh, libgit2sharp

I am curious about the current state of handling SSH-Repos under windows using libgit2sharp. Is it possible to e.g. clone a Repo using SSH (git@github.com:libgit2/libgit2sharp.git) ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v0.21, it's not possible yet.

A Pull request (cf. **[#852](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/852)**) is in progress to make this happen. Feel free to subscribe to it would you like to be notified of its progress.

The plan behind the scene would be to rely on **[libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/)** to make this happen.